google authentication new method, how to call onSignOn()
I used the old method which calls a function onSignIn() after authentication success as follows
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="myid" />

<div class="flex-container">
                <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" id="Gsignin" data-theme="dark" style="width:200%;" title="Authentification Google"></div>              
                <div class="g-signin1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-container">
                 <div class="g-signin1">
                     <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">                     
                     <img src="images/signout.jpg" width="120" id="imgout" alt="SignOut" /></a>
                 </div>
            </div>
  </div>

the new method is as follows,
how to add onsignon on it:
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<div id="g_id_onload" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
            data-client_id="myid"
            data-ux_mode="redirect"
            data-login_uri="http://localhost:64459">
            </div>
            <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" ></div>  

                <div class="flex-container">
                 <div class="g-signin1">
                     <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">                     
                     <img src="images/signout.jpg" width="120" id="imgout" alt="SignOut" /></a>
                 </div>
            </div>


I found the solution: use callback=myfunction
<div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="myid"
    data-context="signin" data-ux_mode="popup" data-callback="handleCredentialResponse" data-auto_prompt="false">
  </div>

  <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-shape="pill" data-theme="filled_blue" data-text="signup_with"
    data-size="large" data-logo_alignment="left" data-width="200">
  </div>

